# How to hyperlink a web address or a non web address in php

Tags: php

I have a website were users enters articles and their reference(like wikipedia). The reference which were saved in the database includes both web address and non web addresses.Currently i am hyper linking the script using google's search?q and its working properly.

```
     echo("<br><a rel=nofollow  target=_blank href='http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($row['ref'])."' class=art>$row[ref]</a>");
```

i want to know whether its possible to automatically detect my reference as a web address or not .if it is a web address then when users click to the hyperlink it goes directly to that website and if not it should hyperlink to google search.

eg:

if user enters this link as reference.hyper link should be to this web address

```
      http://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/capitals
      or
      www.washingtonpost.com/sports/capitals
      or
      washingtonpost.com/sports/capitals
```

or if the user enters reference as below

```
     washingtonpost+sports+capitals
```

it should go to googles search?q

advance thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a regular expresion to see if it is a link and make it a link. Regular expression also makes sure it is valid syntax for a link.

```
 $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
 // The Text you want to filter for urls
 $text = "http://www.google.com"; #The text you want to filter goes here
 // Check if there is a url in the text
 if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
   // make the urls hyper links
   echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);
 } else {
   // if no urls in the text just return the text
   echo '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=',urlencode($text),'">',$text,'</a>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the presence of a `://` to see if the inputted data is a link. It's not perfect, but you could tweak it to meet your needs:

```
$URL = 'http://www.google.com?/q=' . urlencode($Reference);
if (strpos($Reference, '://') !== false)
{
    $URL = $Reference;
}

echo '<a href="' . $Reference . '">' . $Reference . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to automatically detect your reference as a web address or not. You have to check if reference is URL or not.

```
function isValidURL($url) {
  return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```