# whats wrong with this php hyperlinking validation script

Tags: php

I have a website were users enters articles and their reference(like wikipedia). The reference which were saved in the database includes both web address and non web addresses.I got a hyperlink validation script from net ,below is the script and this is my similar but not same query in this site
[How to hyperlink a web address or a non web address in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789562/how-to-hyperlink-a-web-address-or-a-non-web-address-in-php)

```
 //url validation

 if (preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i',  $url))

{
echo("<br><a rel=nofollow  target=_blank href=". urlencode($row['ref'])." class=art>$row[ref]</a>"); 


} 
 //if it is not a url
 else {
  echo("<br><a rel=nofollow  target=_blank href='http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($row['ref'])."' class=art>$row[ref]</a>");
}
```

script is working properly..but it seems the hyperlinking of webaddress is not happening(non webaddress working fine)

```
 eg: if $url is http://www.washingtonpost.com
```

this script is hyperlinking as

```
     www.mywebsite.com/http://www.washingtonpost.com
```

i actually want

```
      http://www.washingtonpost.com
```

can you please help me and also advanced thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML that your code produces. It's hard to understand what is linking/not/how

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you should not use urlencode on a full url.  It will make a url like: http://www.somesite.com/

come out like:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somesite.com%2F

Which will be linked relatively in the same directory as the page it was on.

So: Don't use urlencode for full urls.

Answer (score 0):

remove **urlencode()** at

```
echo("<br><a rel=nofollow  target=_blank href=". urlencode($row['ref'])." class=art>$row[ref]</a>");
```

so your script will be

```
echo("<br><a rel=nofollow  target=_blank href=". $row['ref']." class=art>$row[ref]</a>");
```